# showing json output on google map API v3

Tags: php, json, google-maps-api-3

I have a json output that shows my info correctly but i am having a hell of a time getting it to show a icon on each pair of lat+lng from my DB

Here is my current code

```
<?php

require('inc/db.inc.php');
mysql_connect($connect, $user, $pword) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT store_lat,store_long FROM location WHERE status='Active'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
$locations=(json_encode($output));

?>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;key=MY_API_KEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function initialize() {

    var image = 'images/icon.png';
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.548625, -92.548765);

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var poiJson = <? echo $locations ?>;
    for (var i = 0;i < poiJson.length; i += 1) {
        var lat = poiJson[i].store_lat;
        var lng = poiJson[i].store_long;
        addMarker(lat,lng,i);
        };
}

function addMarker(lat,lng,no){
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
        // if i uncomment the icon line no map will show at all
        //icon: image
        });
}
</script> 

<? include "header.php"; ?>
<p>
<table width="1024">
<tr>
  <td align="center" valign="top"><div id="map_canvas" style="width: 95%; height: 600px;"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</p>
</body> 
</html>
```

Edit

if i change the image into the addMarker function this dose not change anything.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function initialize() {


    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.548625, -92.548765);

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var poiJson = <? echo $locations ?>;
    for (var i = 0;i < poiJson.length; i += 1) {
        var lat = poiJson[i].store_lat;
        var lng = poiJson[i].store_long;
        addMarker(lat,lng,i);
        };
}

function addMarker(lat,lng,no){
    var image = 'images/icon.png';
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
        //icon: image
        });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting. I just wrote a script last night that does exactly you're trying to do. Confirm that the JSON output is what you want. Also try logging calls to `addMarker` to ensure that all the data is being parsed correctly.

Comment: I was able to get this to work on a android app using that same json output so i don't believe the json output to be the issue. I haven't done much with JS before. how can i get some errors so i know whats going on with my code?

Comment: I if view source this is how the json is showing `var poiJson = [{"store_lat":"42968605","store_long":"-81282452"},{"store_lat":"42954525","store_long":"-81289456"}];
 for (var i = 0;i < poiJson.length; i += 1) {` I have about 4000 items in my json output.

Comment: The JSON looks good. Did you try logging your parameters when creating new `LatLng` instances?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `image` defined in the scope of `addMarker` (hence you will get an error). It is only *local* to `initialize`. Either define it in `addMarker` or make it global.

Comment: i have edit above by moving the `var image` into the `function  addMarker` and nothing changes.

Comment: @PsychoDogg: Did you also uncomment the icon line? Is the path correct?

Comment: yes all that was fine i think it is something to do with the lat and lng not being added.